# Data retrieved from MySQL (Using ajax) exceeds destination element defined width

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database

[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crVBY.jpg)
I am retrieving data from Mysql using ajax call.

This is Javascript file:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = this.responseText;
     }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "sample.php?id=" + id, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

This is sample.php file

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT `description` FROM `products` WHERE `id`='$id'";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
$description = mysql_result(query_run,0);
echo $description;
```

I have defined the width of the destination 'div' element to 500px .But the result generating from database exceeds 500px .I want it take next line every time width reaches 500px.Please help me

Comment: this happens because you don't have spaces in description, i think that in real description you will never have word's bigger than 500px

Comment: You can try adding some CSS styles to the DIV - e.g. `word-break: always`, `white-space: wrap`, `overflow-wrap: break-word`. You have to play a little before finding the perfect combination.